# Append json data to html class name

Tags: html, json

I have a problem with my json code.
I want to append each json value comes from a key to be appended to an html class name which matches the key of json data.

here's my [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zj/2/)

if you see the result in the life demo. it's only appending the last record.
is it possible to make it show all records in order?

**json**

```
var json = '[{"castle":"big","commercial":"large","common":"sergio","cultural":"2009"},' + '{"castle":"big2","commercial":"large2","common":"sergio2","cultural":"20092"}]';
```

**html**

```
<div class="castle"></div>
<div class="commercial"></div>
<div class="common"></div>
<div class="cultural"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
var data = $.parseJSON(json);
$.each(data, function(l,v) {
    $.each(v, function(k,o) {
        $('.'+k).attr('id', k+o);
        console.log($('#'+k+o).attr('id'));
        $('#'+k+o).text(o);
     });
});
```

for more illustration...
I want the result in the live demo to look like this

big
large
sergio
2009,
big2
large2
sergio2
20092

Comment: You aren't appending anything to a class name. And you should give your expected HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('#'+k+o).append(o+',');
```

instead of

```
$('#'+k+o).text(o);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zj/3/)

---

But I would use a faster alternative:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
for(var i in data[0]) {
    if(data[0].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var txt = data[0][i];
        for(var j=1; j<data.length; j++) {
            txt += ', ' + data[j][i];
        }
        $('.'+i).text(txt);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zj/5/)

Note that `$.each` is so slow than even jQuery developers recommend using JS loops if possible. And be aware than DOM changes are expensive, so better store your text in a varible, and when you have it all append it, but avoid appending it part by part.

---

If you don't want them mixed, use

```
var data = JSON.parse(json),
    $el = $('#data');
for(var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; ++i) {
    for(var j in data[i]) {
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            $el.append(
                $('<li>')
                    .attr("id",j+data[i][j])
                    .text(data[i][j])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zj/7/)

Comment: do I have to append to another div to make them look in order?

Comment: @user2898514 What do you mean *in order*?

Comment: like this
 big
large
sergio
2009,
big2
large2
sergio2
20092

Comment: appending all of the appended records to another div to make them separate

Comment: @user2898514 Yes, you need different `div`s (but maybe you should use `li`s if you are making a list)

Comment: Does it has to be ul-li to be listed...?

Comment: Thanks A LOTTTTTTTTTTT

Comment: oh, so that's not actually appending to class name :(